# Azure CPU Memory And Percentage

Tags: azure, memory-usage, cloud-hosting

my question is, the memory percentage seems high. We had a client say they couldn't get a response from our APIS over the weekend, and so far i can't see anything in the logs. I can see that they didn't hit our servers apis but i can't tell if its due to the machine not being able to handle these requests.

Should the high percentage concern me? we do heavy caching on site, so maybe that is causing the high memory usage

The current Azure plan we are on is the S1 Standard. 1Core, 1.75Gb Ram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory usage is fairly high, but it's also fairly consistent, only moving about 2% up or down, and not getting to 100%. This is indicative that you are using quite a bit of your current memory allocation but you haven't run out yet. If you know your load is going to to stay the same as shown in this graph then there isn't really a need to change it, however if you are likely to expect an increased load or more spikes in load then you are a close enough to the limit to warrant upgrading to an S2 instance. It really depends on your workload.

If the user complaining didn't actually hit your API and your logs show that then this is not going to be an issue with your memory usage, they never hit the server.

Comment: Would scaling "out" be as effective in this scenario, aka adding more virtual servers, whether by auto-scaling by memory percentage, or just up the minimum virtual servers by 1?

Comment: If your application is built to spread its load over multiple instances then yes. If not, then it's not likely to help much.